# Uninstalling Cisco VPN Client on Windows 7 RC causes machine to BSOD. How can I uninstall it?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, uninstall, cisco-vpn-client

I've installed Cisco Systems VPN Client 5.0.02.0090 on my Windows 7 RC (build 7100) machine and everything worked like a charm.

Unfortunately, when I try to uninstall the Cisco VPN client, after the uninstall process starts, I always get a BSOD (blue screen of death).

How I can successfully uninstall the Cisco VPN client?

Comment: please, specify BSOD message

Comment: It's in the question. BSOD = blue screen of death

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the Cisco virtual network card through the Device Manager first, then you should be able to uninstall client.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: that worked! thx ;)